# Bash: integer expression expected, using read/test

Tags: bash, arithmetic

I'm learning the basics of shell programming, so I wrote something simple like

```
#!/bin/bash
read var1
read var2
if [ var1 -lt var2 ]; then
    echo "var1 is lt var2"
else
    echo "var2 is lt var1"
fi
```

My understanding is that variables are untyped in Bash, and that any variable may be used as an integer if it only contains digits. But I get the error "integer expression expected" when I run this... why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually you can set some attributes on variables using the `declare` (or the old `typeset`) builtin. `declare -i var1 var2` will set integer attribute on those variables. After that assignments which attempt to set non-integer values to those variables will raise error.

But your problem is with the syntax. When using a variable's value you have to prefix its name with `$`:

```
if [ "$var1" -lt "$var2" ]; then
    echo "$var1 is lt $var2"
else
    echo "$var2 is lt $var1"
fi
```

Exceptions are the arithmetic evaluations, where is no need for the `$`:

```
if ((var1<var2)); then
    echo "$var1 is lt $var2"
else
    echo "$var2 is lt $var1"
fi
```

As a word of warning, inside `[`..`]` always double quote your variables to avoid word expansion messing up your expression's syntax. (I mean, you will have problems with unset variables, variables containing empty string and variables containing `IFS` characters.) Or you can use the newer and better `[[`..`]]` instead which handles such cases correctly:

```
if [[ $var1 -lt $var2 ]]; then
    echo "$var1 is lt $var2"
else
    echo "$var2 is lt $var1"
fi
```

Comment: Also, `[[ $var1 < $var2 ]]` is a [string comparison](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html), not an arithmetic comparison...   `[[ 11 > 2 ]]` tests as *false* ... `[[ 11 -gt 2 ]]` tests as true

Comment: @Peter.O, you are right. Since I use only arithmetic evaluation for numeric comparisons, I forgot that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should reference variables prepending the name with `$`

```
if [ $var1 -lt $var2 ] ; then...
```

Comment: And you should quote those variables `"$var1" -lt "$var2"` unless you have a very good reason for not doing so.